# ¿Cómo puedo convertir coordenadas de tipo N 0 W 0 a latitud y longitud?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Quizá no supe buscar en inglés y por eso decidí formular esta pregunta:

Tengo varias coordenadas de tipo:

> **N 7.45.05.34 WO 76.43.41.47**

Necesito convertirlas a coordenadas así:

> **7.888216596715097, -76.63187127560377**

Estoy trabajando con la [API v3 para JavasCript](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/?hl=es-419) de google maps, no adjunto código porque no he encontrado nada en concreto respecto a si esta API permite esta conversión o permite poner marcadores en un mapa fácilitando dichas coordenadas.

Comment: Probablemente esto te sirva: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140189/converting-latitude-and-longitude-to-decimal-values

Comment: Busca por *convertir de sexagesimal a decimal*. Hay tropecientos resultados en Español.

Comment: Se divide los minutos y segundos entre 60.

Comment: Aquí hay mas información sobre esto http://www.coordenadas-gps.com/sistema-de-coordenadas . Al final de la página hay un enlace a un conversor de coordenadas. Quizá me anime a responderte con código :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A la final era algo bastante simple:

1. Tenía que dividir la coordenada en 3 números, lo cual realizé con el siguiente script (teniendo en cuenta que eran muchas coordenadas)
2. Debía hacer una operación básica la cual era:

   > (((SEGUNDOS / 60) + MINUTOS / 60) + GRADOS)

```js
var log = console.log.bind(console);
const div = 60;
var coords = ['N 7.45.5.34 WO 76.43.41.47',
  'N 7.42.38.1 WO 76.44.14.5',
  'N 7.42.34.5  WO 76.45.3.4'
];

coords.forEach((coord, index) => {

  const split = coord.split("WO");
  if (split.length == 2) {
    split[0] = split[0].trim();
    split[0] = split[0].substr(2) + " | ";
    split[1] = split[1].trim();

    const current = split.join().replace(",", "");

    const secondSplit = current.split("|");

    if (secondSplit.length == 2) {

      secondSplit[0] = secondSplit[0].trim();
      var lat = secondSplit[0].split(".");
      if (lat.length == 4) {
        var superLat = " " + lat[0] + " " + lat[1] + " " + lat[2] + "." + lat[3] + " - ";
      }

      secondSplit[1] = secondSplit[1].trim();
      var lng = secondSplit[1].split(".");
      if (lng.length == 4) {
        var superLng = lng[0] + " " + lng[1] + " " + lng[2] + "." + lng[3];
      }

      const superCoord = superLat + superLng;
      const coordSplit = superCoord.split(" - ");
      const currentLat = coordSplit[0].trim();
      const currentLng = coordSplit[1].trim();
      const latSplit = currentLat.split(" ");
      const lngSplit = currentLng.split(" ");
      const finalLat = (((Math.round(parseInt(latSplit[2])) / div) + parseInt(latSplit[1])) / div) + parseInt(latSplit[0]);
      const finalLng = (((Math.round(parseInt(lngSplit[2])) / div) + parseInt(lngSplit[1])) / div) + parseInt(lngSplit[0]);

      log(superCoord + " = " + finalLat + ", " + finalLng)
    }

  }

})
```